# Is there a way to stop `git diff-tool` when return code is non-zero from the diff-tool is non-zero

Tags: git, diff, vimdiff, difftool, git-difftool

I am aware of the `git config` option `difftool.prompt true`

However, I am wondering if there is a way to stop diffing when return code is non-zero.  I am using `vim` as diff-tool and if I exit using `:cq` it will return non-zero but the default settings of `git` do not stop diffing the remaining files when it gets non-zero return code.

I guess this makes sense since some tools will return non-zero code when files differ and most people will not want to stop at this point, however, in my case it will return non-zero only if I `vim` encounter an error or if I asked it to do and in these cases I will always want `git diff-tool` to stop.

So is there a way to change the default setting to stop when received a non-zero return code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once:

```
git difftool --trust-exit-code
```

Permanet:

```
git config difftool.trustExitCode true
```

See the docs: [1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt---no-trust-exit-code), [2](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt-difftooltrustExitCode).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: The documentation is wrong as of git 2.43.0. If the external command exits with a nonzero code, the exit status of `git difftool --trust-exit-code ...` is 128. I'd report and/or fix the bug if it wasn't such a hassle.

Comment: The docs: "*Use `--trust-exit-code` to make **git-difftool** exit when an invoked diff tool returns a non-zero exit code. **git-difftool** will forward the exit code of the invoked tool when `--trust-exit-code` is used.*" I don't see how this contradicts to what you said.

Answer (score 1):

`difftool.trustExitCode` will also work with `git difftool --dir-diff` now.

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b387623c12f3f4a376e4d35a610fd3e55d7ea907), "[`git difftool --dir-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a87469cc99408d515569ec490726eededbcfa063/Documentation/git-difftool.txt#L23)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt---dir-diff))</sup> learned to honor the `--trust-exit-code` option; it used to always exit with 0 and signalled success.

See [commit eb84c8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb84c8b6cef15fcd048711afce46ce40dc5c43f5) (20 Feb 2024) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a87469c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a87469cc99408d515569ec490726eededbcfa063), 01 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`git-difftool--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb84c8b6cef15fcd048711afce46ce40dc5c43f5): honor `--trust-exit-code` with `--dir-diff`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jean-Rémy Falleri</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> The `--trust-exit-code` option for git-diff-tool(1) was introduced via [2b52123](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b52123fcf840686b69e10807fd0f985ec4167f3) ("`difftool`: add support for `--trust-exit-code`", 2014-10-26, Git v2.2.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ce57f12280eb6a95043e28ad68ff2b6c70c09ad)).
> When set, it makes us return the exit code of the invoked diff tool when diffing multiple files.
> This patch didn't change the code path where `--dir-diff` was passed because we already returned the exit code of the diff tool unconditionally in that case.
>
> This was changed a month later via [c41d3fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c41d3fedd8a5dec2c2c991822b70b91c50ca047e) ("`difftool--helper`: add explicit exit statement", 2014-11-20, Git v2.3.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ddedd4d6b9b3e8eb3557d8ed28e1a0b354a25f8) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9abc44b681a669c67d071d858c8aad21f65a0956)), where an explicit `exit 0` was added to the end of git-difftool--helper.sh.
> While the stated intent of that commit was merely a cleanup, it had the consequence that we now to ignore the exit code of the diff tool when `--dir-diff` was set.
> This change in behaviour is thus very likely an unintended side effect of this patch.
>
> Now there are two ways to fix this:
>
> - We can either restore the original behaviour, which unconditionally returned the exit code of the diffing tool when `--dir-diff` is passed.
> - Or we can make the `--dir-diff` case respect the `--trust-exit-code` flag.
>
> The fact that we have been ignoring exit codes for 7 years by now makes me rather lean towards the latter option.
> Furthermore, respecting the flag in one case but not the other would needlessly make the user interface more complex.
>
> Fix the bug so that we also honor `--trust-exit-code` for dir diffs and adjust the documentation accordingly.